# Calling "mysqldump" with Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) from Windows 7

Tags: java, mysql, runtime.exec

I am trying to dump a MySQL database within my Java application the following way:

```
String[] command = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "C:/mysql/mysqldump.exe" --quick --lock-tables --user=\"root\" --password=\"mypwd\" mydatabase > \"C:/mydump.sql\""};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
int exitcode = process.waitFor();
```

The process fails with exit-code 6. I somewhere read that the operand ">" is not correctly interpreted and there was the hint to use "cmd.exe /c" as prefix. But it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You copy/pasted to much of the command I think. The command is piping output to a file. If you invoke this through Java then you don't do that, you capture the output of the process and do the writing to the file in the Java code.

Comment: The command by itself is correct. But you're right, that piping is somehow not supported by the Runtime library. I'll try to write the process output to the file by hand. Thanks so far!

Comment: Btw: piping resp. re-direction works with Runtime.exec() on Linux and I think also on MacOS.

Comment: Architecturally it makes little sense to do however. IMO of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here's the final solution. You need to put the "process-reader to file-writer" code into a separate thread and finally wait for the process object to be finished:

```
    // define backup file
    File fbackup = new File("C:/backup.sql");
    // execute mysqldump command
    String[] command = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "C:/path/to/mysqldump.exe --quick --lock-tables --user=myuser --password=mypwd mydatabase"};
    final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    // write process output line by line to file
    if(process!=null) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(process.getInputStream()))); 
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fbackup))) {
                        String line;
                        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)   {
                            writer.write(line);
                            writer.newLine();
                        }
                    }
                } catch(Exception ex){
                    // handle or log exception ...
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
    if(process!=null && process.waitFor()==0) {
        // success ...
    } else {
        // failed
    }
```

On Linux you can directly re-direct the output of the command to a file by using ">" as usual... (and also on Mac OS X I think). So no need for the thread. Generally, please avoid white spaces in your path to the mysqldump/mysqldump.exe file!

Comment: its not working , not able to create database backup

Comment: what exactly is the problem? please provide some output. what OS you're using?

Comment: i am using windows 10, mysql server 5.6 , jdk 1.7 and issue is else part i.e. failed part is executing where process.waitFor()!=0

Comment: Please check if you correctly have replaced all the variables in "String command = ..." to your sytem environment, i.e. mysql user+pwd, db-schema and the path to your mysqldump.exe. If still not working, try the composited command string from your windows shell. Otherwise post the stacktrace of the exceptions and/or the exit code from the waitFor() method.

Comment: String command[] = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\bin\\mysqldump "+" --quick --lock-tables --user=root --password=pass test1"};
This is my query
and none of exceptions were thrown during execution

Comment: checking wait for method

      try {
          if(process!=null && process.waitFor()==0) {
              System.out.println("success");
          
          } else {
              System.out.println("fail");
             // failed
         }
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Temp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }

Comment: 1 problem that I am facing is ,when i am running a command using cmd it is giving access is denied ,while running cmd as administrator it is working fine, do u think above problem has something to do regarding this?

Comment: you forgot to append ".exe" after mysqldump. if still not working, System.out.println(command) and try to execute in the windows terminal. moreover i would highly recommend to install mysqldump to a location without whitespaces in the path! this always leads to problems in windows.

Comment: this also might be a problem. go to UAC (user access control) in your windows settings and lower the security checks for your user and try again.

Comment: I didnot get it, running from cmd it works fine, but through java program it doesnot .. can u tell me the possible reason for that?

Comment: insert Sytem.out.println(command[2]); after the line String[] command = ... and copy/paste this manually to your windows shell for testing the command. when you managed to work it there, copy it back to your java program. dont forget to add .exe and reinstall mysqldump.exe to a location without white spaces. let me know if it worked. i will be back in 8 hrs, i need a sleep.

Comment: infact i used the same query to create batch file ,it works fine

Comment: process.waitFor() returns the exit-code of the process. insert System.out.println(process.waitFor()); before if(process!=null ...). if its !=0 there was an execution error => google for that exit code.

Comment: it says 1 ,and as per google only 0 is defined while for 1 it only means abnormal termination

Comment: 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
it means this

Comment: then probably there's a problem with your path to mysqldump. did you add .exe? try to copy mysqldump.exe to C:/mysqldump.exe and adjust your command[] accordingly. white spaces in paths on windows are really the hell!

Comment: yes i did ,and shocking thing is it recognize command if I am running on cmd
And yes placing it directly under C: it worked
Thanks a lot man..!!

Comment: This is great, but spawning a new thread isn't necessary because the buffered stream copy logic will block the current thread as much as the `process.waitFor()` will, I mean, it's perfectly possible to save on thread spawning time and ram cost there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are right , some days ago I made class for exporting DataBase from MySQL...
You coud read output sream from console and then write to file

```
    String[] command = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "\"C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin/mysqldump.exe\" --quick --lock-tables --user=\"root\" --password=\"mypwd\" mydatabase "};
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println(line); //there you can write file 
    }
    input.close();
```

Best Regards