# Run cmd as administrator using Java Code

Tags: java, mysql, windows, cmd

I want to execute the following mysql query, using java code:

```
mysqldump -uroot -ppassword temp1>C:\abc.sql
```

After a lot of search I found out that this needs cmd to run as admin I don't know how to run as admin using java code.
I tried this but it doesn't work

```
runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "runas /profile /user:Administrator \"cmd.exe", executeCmd });
```

Does any one has any idea regarding this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596599/run-command-prompt-as-administrator

Comment: yes it is,but i am not getting how to use elevate in my case , It would be good if u can help me regarding that @boly38

Comment: And this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/24887927/1827276

Comment: its not working too, i tried that, there is issue regarding access rights, mysqldump command doesnot work without run as admin,I tried mysqldump with normal cmd, it gives error of access denied.

Comment: Are you sure this error occurs because of missing admin rights ? I see no reason why a database connection should fail because if wrong Windows permissions.

Comment: agree. use same windows user as your java app to execute mysqldump to test it.

Comment: yes ,I got the reason ,I was trying to right file in C: where my Os is installed and for that reason it was asking for admin right ,after changing path to other drive it worked fine.
Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `runas /savecred` to execute, but I suggest you use JNI instead:

[CreateProcessWithLogonW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can find examples here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2007/12/20/how-to-call-createprocesswithlogonw-createprocessasuser-in-net.aspx

Comment: Will my statement look like this ??

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe ","/c","runas /savecred", executeCmd })

Comment: @Varun Should be like this: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"runas /savecred /user:theDomain\\administrator yourCommand\"");

Comment: okay this is nice...! thanks for clarifying this :D